# Dash in a field name in access database table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-design

Im having problems retrieving a field from my ms-access database.

The table name is TEST and one of the field's name is HD-TEST

When i do:

SELECT * from TEST where TEST.HD-TEST='H' and i execute the query, ms-access shows me a dialog expecting the parameter HD.

Do you know what could be the reason?

Thanks a lot.
Kind Regards.
Josema.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to add brackets to the begin and the end of the column name (not tested, but works in SQL Server):

```
SELECT * from TEST where TEST.[HD-TEST]='H'
```