# Syntax Error Insert Into statement java

Tags: java, sql, syntax-error, execute, insert-into

I want to add a dataset into my MS Acces Database. But I always get a Syntax Error in the SQL Statements exactly at the executeUpdate Statement. If someone could help me, that would be great.

Here you can see the Error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC-Treiber für Microsoft Access] Syntaxfehler in der INSERT INTO-Anweisung.
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at verwaltung.ListenerRegistrieren.addBenutzer(ListenerRegistrieren.java:47)
at verwaltung.ListenerRegistrieren.actionPerformed(ListenerRegistrieren.java:28)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And this is the code which the Error is based on. It is in the **executeUpdate()** - Statement :

```
try {

    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:MSAccess");
    PreparedStatement pstm;
    pstm = conn.prepareStatement("Insert Into Benutzer (Benutzername, Vorname, Nachname, E-Mail) values (?,?,?,?)");

    // SQL Statements
    pstm.setString(1, gui.benutzername.getText());
    pstm.setString(2, gui.vorname.getText());
    pstm.setString(3, gui.nachname.getText());
    pstm.setString(4, gui.email.getText());
    pstm.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I can't find the Syntax Error! Can someone help me?

thank you

Comment: Does your table contain 4 columns?

Comment: I suspect the hyphen in E-Mail causes trouble

Comment: @ihsankocak no it contains more but I only want to fill in 4 in this insert statement.

Comment: @bowmore I changed the name to eMail in my db and in my programm but it doesn't work it says: it doesn't find this column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The E-Mail column has a hyphen in it, you should escape it. See this answer for how to do that : [Dash in a field name in access database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756972/dash-in-a-field-name-in-access-database-table)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the values of all the columns in your table, else java JDBC will throw and error.

If you have a table users with 2 columns username and password your code will look as follow for your prepareStatement.

`pstm = conn.prepareStatement("Insert Into users values ('YourName', 'Password')");`